# Why do i need to clean my project everytime i run it? otherwise it gives an error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-camera

Error is in this line:

```
 camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

After clean everything works ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your project MIN_SDK. 
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90) will only work since API level 8.
If you are targeting any device before Android FROYO, it wont work